# I am trying to find XP drivers for Dell Vostro 1015

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I need display and network drivers in particular. I got this laptop at work after my previous one bailed out on me.

I have tried the dell drivers site and also had a live chat with a rep, but they couldn't help me. Is there any similar model which has XP drivers available much more effortlessly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drivers you need are on the Dell site, what problems are you having finding them?

If you punch in your service tag number on the driver page it will return only the drivers for your particular build, this is helpful when Dell has multiple selections of network drivers, use your service tag number to find your particular drivers.

Go to this page and click "Change your product" and then enter your service tag number

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WW1&catid=-1&dateid=-1&impid=-1&osl=EN&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=VOS_N_1015&hidos=WLH&hidlang=en&TabIndex=&scanSupported=False&scanConsent=False

I don't recommend using their download manager, use your browser to download the drivers instead.

.

Answer (score 1):

[DriverPacks.Net](http://www.driverpacks.net) Has a method for building a standalone driver CD.  Following the instructions from the site, you can build a CD with only LAN drivers (so as not to disturb your existing, working drivers) and usually get good results.

Since you've had this problem, I would use a utility like [Double Driver](http://www.boozet.org/dd.htm) to back up your drivers.

Comment: I have just looked at driverpacks.net. But there is a vast range in that website. Could you please be a little specific , about how to get to the point to download VOSTRO 1015 XP Drivers?

Comment: Well, no... the driverpacks database is loaded with nearly every driver out there, so when you build the LAN drivers CD and run it, it will scan your system and find the correct driver... about 99% of the time. :)

Answer (score 1):

All the [drivers for Dell Vostro 1015](http://www.all-driver.com/notebook-driver/dell-vostro-1015-drivers.html) laptop an easy way to download from the link in the connection.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Get all your drivers from [Dell](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WW1&osl=FR&catid=-1&impid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=VOS_N_1015&hidos=WLH&hidlang=fr&TabIndex=).

Comment: The OP has already tried this.

Comment: I never had a case where I didn't find my drivers on the Dell site. @Animesh: Did you access the Dell site user your Dell Service Tag? If that's the case, then Dell simply doesn't support XP on your model. You can try to identify compatible drivers, but this is a lot of work and some drivers you might never find.

Comment: @harry: Yes, i have contacted the Dell Support guys and they have said the drivers will not be available online as this laptop is compatible with Ubantu, Windows 7 or Vista. The resource CD that i have go has got no drivers in it.

Comment: So XP isn't and will never be supported. The Dell support site shows only Vista drivers for this model. Under another OS it will be almost impossible to find drivers for ALL the hardware (been there). But still, Dell PCs always come with OS, so how did you ever end up without any OS? If you don't choose Ubuntu (warning : where are the drivers?), your only other solution is currently Vista.

Comment: In case of no OS: Dell PCs always have a recovery partition. Why not use it to reinstall the original OS it came with? (note that all data will be lost).

Comment: I will reinstall the OS, that is the only option I have now anyway. Thanks.